# gzstream on windows via mingw: injects CR + LF

Tags: c++, compression, gzip, zlib

I downloaded the source from [the site](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/compgeom/gzstream/) and built it but when I run the test, all of the zipped files have CR+LF line endings rather than just LF which makes the unzipped files different from the originals.

I'm looking at the source but it seems like they are already opening the file in binary mode:

```
gzstreambuf* gzstreambuf::open( const char* name, int open_mode) {
    if ( is_open())
        return (gzstreambuf*)0;
    mode = open_mode;
    // no append nor read/write mode
    if ((mode & std::ios::ate) || (mode & std::ios::app)
        || ((mode & std::ios::in) && (mode & std::ios::out)))
        return (gzstreambuf*)0;
    char  fmode[10];
    char* fmodeptr = fmode;
    if ( mode & std::ios::in)
        *fmodeptr++ = 'r';
    else if ( mode & std::ios::out)
        *fmodeptr++ = 'w';
    *fmodeptr++ = 'b';
    *fmodeptr = '\0';
    file = gzopen( name, fmode);
    if (file == 0)
        return (gzstreambuf*)0;
    opened = 1;
    return this;
}
```

I'd really like to use this bit of code because it looks very clean and it compiled effortlessly on mingw gcc. The only problem is this tricky business which I could let slide if I can figure out a solution for it.

Comment: are you sure that it is this code that is injecting those CR+LF? perhaps it is different program (used editor while opening/saving?)

Comment: The code calls this function to zip and unzip the test file. I run them from the command line (and so does the makefile). I cannot determine if it is zlib's `gzopen` which is causing the incorrect `\n` to `\r\n` translation or not.

Comment: How are you checking that your file has incorrect CR+LF? have you tried using binary editor to comapre files before and after compression and decompression - without using any text editor that might do it on the way?

Comment: Well, I look at them in explorer, the decompressed file is 27KB while the original is 26KB. During `make test`, `diff` reports that every single line is different. I opened it using Notepad++ and turned on the nonprinting char display, and it has [CR][LF] at the end of each line. Before I did any of that I md5'd them and they were clearly different. Anyways, I found this: http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/02/23/how-to-use-zlib/ Using zlib directly doesn't look so hard. I'm going to give it a shot. It's neat too, because I'm sure I've seen user bobobobo around here on SO before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've successfully implemented my workaround. Though gzstream looks nice I bit the bullet and just wrote some code that directly uses zlib. Turns out it wasn't bad **at all** because zlib has helpers hidden away in there, and also plenty of helpful comments in `zlib.h` itself.

`ZEXTERN int ZEXPORT compress OF((Bytef *dest, uLongf *destLen, const Bytef *source, uLong sourceLen));` is simple enough.

And of course, no more problems with spurious `0x0D` carriage-return chars!

Answer (score 1):

Where is std::ios::binary??

On UNIX platforms it is often unnecessary so some people omit it when they should not.

Comment: Well, I was passing it to `gzstreambuf::open`. I did check in gdb that gzopen did end up getting called with the binary flag, also.